# Listing Windows file types

Tags: java, windows

How can a Java program get the list of File Types in Windows (those listed in Control Panel/Folder Options/File Types)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of all registered file types is present in the registry under the **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** key. If the key begins with a `.` it is a registered file extension.

Take a look at [MSDN > File Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information about how they are stored in the registry.

You can query the registry using the `reg` command. For example, in a Command Prompt type the following command to list out the file extensions.

```
reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT | find "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\."
```

To execute this from a java program, use a [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: Further reading here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java